# Bootstrap or CSS: How do I tell the browser to center a non-responsive image on mobile?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am very interested in getting the same effect, as they have on Flickr.com, where the pictures aren't getting smaller when the screen is made smaller, the smaller screen  just focus on a smaller part of the picture.

How do i get this effect by using bootstrap or custom CSS?

[The flickr site on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23ZQW.jpg)

[The flickr site on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjbVc.png)

I hope someone are able to help.

Comment: Use a combination of `background-position:fixed;` and `background-size`

Comment: If any of these answers were helpful, please mark one as correct so other people with the same problem can find it. Otherwise, please elaborate as to why these solutions were unhelpful.